# How to change option names in symfony2 form select element

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I run this code to get my select control and it works fine.

```
    $builder
        ->add('access', 'entity', array(
            'label' => 'Behörigheter',
            'multiple' => true,   // Multiple selection allowed
            'expanded' => true,   // Render as checkboxes
            'property' => 'name',
            'class'    => 'BizTV\ContainerManagementBundle\Entity\Container',
            'query_builder' => function(\Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository $er) use ($company) {
                $qb = $er->createQueryBuilder('a');
                $qb->innerJoin('a.containerType', 'ct');
                $qb->where('a.containerType IN (:containers)', 'a.company = :company');
                $qb->setParameters( array('containers' => array(1,2,3,4), 'company' => $company) );
                $qb->orderBy('ct.id', 'ASC');

                return $qb;
            }
        ));
```

Now I want to be able to customize he label for the checkboxes, I learnt just the other day that by changing property to select_label and defining that function in the entity you can accomplish this, but with this query it doesn't work.

Is this because I am joining? Is there a way to accomplish it?

This is the code that doesn't work

```
    $builder
        ->add('access', 'entity', array(
            'label' => 'Behörigheter',
            'multiple' => true,   // Multiple selection allowed
            'expanded' => true,   // Render as checkboxes
            'property' => 'select_label',
            'class'    => 'BizTV\ContainerManagementBundle\Entity\Container',
            'query_builder' => function(\Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository $er) use ($company) {
                $qb = $er->createQueryBuilder('a');
                $qb->innerJoin('a.containerType', 'ct');
                $qb->where('a.containerType IN (:containers)', 'a.company = :company');
                $qb->setParameters( array('containers' => array(1,2,3,4), 'company' => $company) );
                $qb->orderBy('ct.id', 'ASC');

                return $qb;
            }
        ));
```

In the entity I have:

```
public function getSelectLabel()
{
    return $this->name . ' (' . $this->parent->getName() . ')';
}
```

It works fine for another form that has a SELECT (single choice) control, but not for this one...

The error I get is

Fatal error: Call to a member function getName() on a non-object in /var/www/biztv_symfony/src/BizTV/ContainerManagementBundle/Entity/Container.php on line 190

Comment: Is the property name in your entity really select_label? Please keep in mind that you have to specify the PHP property name for the property attribute not the database name

Comment: Put the code of your entity. Do you have the method with name 'getSelectLabel()' in this entity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh sorry guys, I had a few objects in there that didn't have $this->parent defined, I rewrote my name function as follows and it works fine.

```
public function getSelectLabel()
{
    if (isset($this->parent)) {
        return $this->name . ' (' . $this->parent->getName() . ')';
    }
    else {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

Thanks all!